# populating the reactive controls in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a reactive form which lists the name of the firms in the table. When I click the edit button it toggles to show the row with input control.  At the moment, I am initializing the formcontrol to be blank before calling the getFirms. I need that input control to be populated with the firm name. So when the user clicks the edit button input control with that firm name is shown.

html

```
<form [formGroup]="frmFirm">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 30%">Firm Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let firm of Firms">
        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.id]">{{firm.firmName}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="EditMode[firm.id]"><input type="text" formControlName="firmName" class="form-control col-md-3" /></td>

        <td *ngIf="EditMode[firm.id]" style="white-space: nowrap">
          <button (click)="saveUser(firm.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Save</button>
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.id]" style="white-space: nowrap">
          <button (click)="editUser(firm.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</button>
          <button (click)="deleteUser(firm.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-firm" [disabled]="firm.isDeleting">
            <span *ngIf="firm.isDeleting" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
            <span *ngIf="!firm.isDeleting">Delete</span>
          </button>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="!Users">
        <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
          <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-lg align-center"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForModel();
    this.getFirms();

  }

  initializeForModel() {
    this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
     firmName: ['']
    });
  }

  public getFirms() {
    this.userService.getFirms().subscribe((data: IFirm[]) => {
      this.Firms = data;
      //this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
    });
  }
```

Interface

```
export interface IFirm {
 id: number;
 firmName: string;
 isDeleting: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just in the button edit pass the whole firm. Futhermore if you use `[style.display]="!EditMode[firm.id]?'none':null"` instead `*ngIf="EditMode[Firm.id]"`, and use a template variable reference you can make the focus

```
    <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.id]">{{firm.firmName}}</td>
    <td [style.display]="!EditMode[firm.id]?'none':null">
       <input #inputId type="text" formControlName="firmName" class="form-control col-md-3" />
    </td>
    ...
    <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.id]" style="white-space: nowrap">
       <button (click)="editUser(firm,inputId)"..>
    </td>
```

and

NOTE: If your "firm" has not the same properties than the FormGroup,you should use `patchValue` instead of `setValue`

**Update** Sorry, really has no sense only create the formGroup if we not change in the save.

if in the *ngFor we add to know the index, we can pass to save the index

```
   <tr *ngFor="let firm of Firms;let i=index">
    ...
      <button (click)="saveUser(i)"
   </tr>


    //in save
    save(index:number){
        this.Firm[i]={...this.frmFirm.value}
    }
```

Comment: I know this is another question but related to the edit though .How do I modify that value when i click the save so that the modified value is seen on the form

Comment: Sorry, @Tom, your'e correct, has no much sense can not save the value modified, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not good with form builder here is how i would do using another approach

for checking i am getting firmData from 'tempFirms()'

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4lupq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

TS file :-

```
interface IFirm {
  id: number;
  firmName: string;
  isDeleting: boolean;
}
```

Logic inside Component Ts

```
  frmFirm: FormGroup;
  Firms: IFirm[];
  EditMode = [];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForModel();
    this.getFirms();
  }

  initializeForModel() {
    this.frmFirm = new FormGroup({
      firmName: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  public getFirms() {
    let firmName = new FormArray([]);

    this.tempFirms().subscribe((data: IFirm[]) => {
      for (let firm of data) {
        firmName.push(
          new FormGroup({
            id: new FormControl(firm.id),
            firmName: new FormControl(firm.firmName),
            isDeleting: new FormControl(firm.isDeleting)
          })
        );
      }

      this.frmFirm = new FormGroup({
        firmName: firmName
      });
    });
  }

  public tempFirms() {
    return of([
      { id: 1, firmName: "Test 1", isDeleting: false },
      { id: 2, firmName: "Test 2", isDeleting: false }
    ]);
  }

  public editUser(id: number) {
    this.EditMode[id] = true;
  }

  get firmName_controls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.frmFirm.get("firmName")).controls;
  }

  deleteUser(id: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.frmFirm.get("firmName")).removeAt(id - 1);
  }
```

HTML:-

```
<form [formGroup]="frmFirm">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 30%">Firm Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody formArrayName="firmName">
      <tr *ngFor="let firm of firmName_controls ;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.get('id').value]">{{firm.get('firmName').value}}</td>

        <td *ngIf="EditMode[firm.get('id').value]">
          <input type="text"
         formControlName="firmName"
         class="form-control col-md-3" />
        </td>

        <td *ngIf="EditMode[firm.get('id').value]" style="white-space: nowrap">
          <button (click)="saveUser(firm.get('id').value)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Save</button>
        </td>

        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[firm.get('id').value]" style="white-space: nowrap">
          <button (click)="editUser(firm.get('id').value)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</button>
          <button (click)="deleteUser(firm.get('id').value)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-firm" [disabled]="firm.get('isDeleting').value">
            <span *ngIf="firm.get('isDeleting').value" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
            <span *ngIf="!firm.get('isDeleting').value">Delete</span>
          </button>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="!Users">
        <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
          <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-lg align-center"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it the right way of exposing vis this property and accessing it in the template get firmName_controls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.frmFirm.get("firmName")).controls;
  }

Comment: Yes no worries its just a getter used to access form controls and recommended to do so after angular 8.